# What can affect decryption speed in Android?

Tags: android, encryption

I have a very simple method for decryption of messages which I use on Android:

```
PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CBCBlockCipher(new AESFastEngine()));
cipher.init(false, new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(bookKeyData), iv));
int outputSize = cipher.getOutputSize(data.length);
outBuf = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(outputSize)];
int processed = cipher.processBytes(data, 0, data.length, outBuf, 0);
if (processed < outputSize) {
    processed += cipher.doFinal(outBuf, processed);
}
return Arrays.copyOfRange(outBuf, 0, processed);
```

I use Spongy Castle 1.54.0.0 (latest at the time of writing).

Because on some of our devices, the decryption took longer than expected, I have created a benchmark to test it and I have very strange results:
The same device running Android 5.0.1 will have an average of 3000ms to decrypt a message, where when using Android 7.0 it will have an average of 70ms.

I am quite amazed by it. It is the exact same device. Normally I would understand that something could be improved in Android 7 when it comes to decryption, but I am using Spongy Castle libraries with the exact same version.

Is there any reason why it would work this way?
Is there something I could `do/port/override` to improve decryption speed on older Android versions?

I have already tried to change `byte[]` decryption into `Stream`, but the results were exactly the same.

Comment: How do you do to have the same device (or two devices with same model) one with Android 5 and the other with Android 7?

Comment: It's very simple. I bought two exactly same devices and I have not upgraded one of them to a newer version. I do the same with iOS devices to be able to test behavior on different versions of OS.

Comment: Interesting. Thx!

Comment: You don't show what / how you measure the time .. Initialization/load of the crypto provider with the first usage can easily have a 3000 ms overhead. Exactly what are you measuring ?

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen I get `System.currentTimeMillis()` before calling this method and I calculate the time it took afterward. It's by no means a scientific approach, I just run it 1000 times and that's it. It simulates best the behavior of my app where this is used. The decryption time is consistent during runtime.

Comment: At some point along Android's evolution the default crypto provider changed from one based on pure Java bouncycastle to one based on a mixed Java/native OpenSSL hybrid. It's likely your seeing a speedup due to native code on later versions.

Comment: @JamesKPolk but I am using Spongy Castle as the provider

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, that is confusing.

Comment: @zaph Eh, no. The **Lightweight API**, i.e. `AESFastEngine` is a pure Java implementation. That does mean that it depends a lot on the JIT compiler of the Android version that is used, of course.